# matrix library: inline vs define

Tags: c, optimization

I'm creating a matrix library with a bunch of function like this one (it's actually a long one):

```
void matx_multiply(int x, float mat1[], float mat2[], float result[])
{
    int row,col,k;

    for (row=0; row<x; row++) {
        for(col=0; col<x; col++){
            result[row + col*x]=0.0f;
            for (k=0; k<x; k++)
            {
                result[row + col*x]+=mat1[row + k*x]*mat2[k + col*x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly, I wonder if it's better to change this to an `inline` function if it is use ~5 times in a program (often in a loop), with `x` being known at compile time.

I think it's better to `inline` it, so the compiler can decide at compile time whether we want it to be expanded in the code or not (depending on the optimization parameter). In addition, the compiler might fairly well optimize the loop if it knows `x` (for example, if x=2, it may decide to unroll the loop)

More importantly, I want to add a set of functions:

```
#define mat2_multiply(m1,m2,res) matx_multiply(2,m1,m2,res)
#define mat3_multiply(m1,m2,res) matx_multiply(3,m1,m2,res)
...
```

or

```
static inline void mat2_multiply(float mat1[static 2],
                                 float mat2[static 2],
                                 float result[static 2])
{
    matx_multiply(2,mat1,mat2,result);
}
...
```

or creating a function (but it create a function call for nothing)

- One way is much more concise and is always expanded (it will verify if mat1 and mat2 are array of float anyway)
- The second way is more secure, it verify the length of the array, but it's less concies and may not be expanded...

What would you do, and what would you want a matrix library to do ?

I want my library to be fairly fast (for OpenGL app), fairly small and easy to use.

Comment: Write test for typical use-case, and do a benchmark.

Comment: if the compiler expand the function, it should be the same as a define, if it does not, it should be the same as a simple function declaration... In addition, I would have to do a benchmark for each functions.
I'd rather want to know if a matrix library that aim to be fairly fast and small should inline its functions or not.
And maybe there are other advantages/techniques that I don't know yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `inline` keyword. There are several disadvantages if you use the preprocessor to develop function-like macros:

- no type safety checking
- no sanity checking
- bad to debug
- bad readability
- expressions passed to macros can be evaluated more than [once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf6bf4cf.aspx)

Comment: * type safety is ensure anyway, because the macros will be expanded to a simple call to max_multiply(...), which is not a macro.

* readability is, in my opinion not better with inline functions in this case
could you develop your arguments?

Comment: If you think so you can use the preprocessor. I wouldn't do it in your case.

Comment: Yes, debugging and macro-related-side-effects make me prefer inline.  Thanks :)